# Django view doesn’t recognize the parameter name from template

Tags: django, templates, view, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass two parameters from template (“**zn**” and “**ru**”) to filter posts in view. It seems to me, that the variables of both parameters are OK, but not under proper name. The view probably doesn’t recognize which is which. Filtering with parameter “**zn**” works, but filtering with parameter “**ru**” doesn’t (see the error statement in picture).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msntX.png)

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("clanky/", views.clanek_vyber, name="clanky_vyber", kwargs={'zn': '', 'ru': ''}),
    path("clanky/<slug:zn>/", views.clanek_vyber, name="clanky_vyber", kwargs={'ru': ''}),
    path("clanky/<slug:ru>/", views.clanek_vyber, name="clanky_vyber", kwargs={'zn': ''}),
    path("clanky/<slug:zn>/<slug:ru>/", views.clanek_vyber, name="clanky_vyber"),
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views import generic
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
...

from .models import Clanek, Rubrika, Znacka, GalerieObrazku, Hlavni_banner
...

def clanek_vyber(request, zn, ru):
    bannery_1 = Hlavni_banner.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')[:1]

    clanek_znacka = Clanek.objects.values('znacka')
    znac = Znacka.objects.filter(id__in=clanek_znacka)
    rubr = Clanek.objects.distinct('rubrika').order_by('rubrika_id')

    if (zn!="" and ru!=""):
        uvodni_clanek = Clanek.objects.filter(znacka__slug=zn).filter(rubrika__slug=ru).order_by('-published_date')[:1]
        zna = Znacka.objects.get(slug=zn)
        rub = Rubrika.objects.get(slug=ru)
        cla_vyb = Clanek.objects.filter(znacka__slug=zn).filter(rubrika__slug=ru).order_by('-published_date')[1:]
        paginator = Paginator(cla_vyb, 20) # ukáže dvacet dalších článků
        page_number = request.GET.get("page")
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
        context = {
            'bannery_1': bannery_1,
            'uvodni_clanek': uvodni_clanek,
            'page_obj': page_obj,
            'znac': znac,
            'zna': zna,
            'zn': zn,
            'rubr': rubr,
            'rub': rub,
            'ru': ru
            }
        return render(request, "zentour/clanky.html", context)

    if(zn!=""):
        uvodni_clanek = Clanek.objects.filter(znacka__slug=zn).order_by('-published_date')[:1]
        zna = Znacka.objects.get(slug=zn)
        cla_vyb = Clanek.objects.filter(znacka__slug=zn).order_by('-published_date')[1:]
        paginator = Paginator(cla_vyb, 20) # ukáže dvacet dalších článků
        page_number = request.GET.get("page")
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
        context = {
            'bannery_1': bannery_1,
            'uvodni_clanek': uvodni_clanek,
            'page_obj': page_obj,
            'znac': znac,
            'zna': zna,
            'zn': zn,
            'rubr': rubr
            }
        return render(request, "zentour/clanky.html", context)

    elif(ru!=""):
        uvodni_clanek = Clanek.objects.filter(rubrika__slug=ru).order_by('-published_date')[:1]
        rub = Rubrika.objects.get(slug=ru)
        cla_vyb = Clanek.objects.filter(rubrika__slug=ru).order_by('-published_date')[1:]
        paginator = Paginator(cla_vyb, 20) # ukáže dvacet dalších článků
        page_number = request.GET.get("page")
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
        context = {
            'bannery_1': bannery_1,
            'uvodni_clanek': uvodni_clanek,
            'page_obj': page_obj,
            'znac': znac,
            'rubr': rubr,
            'rub': rub,
            'ru': ru
            }
        return render(request, "zentour/clanky.html", context)

    else:
        uvodni_clanek = Clanek.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')[:1]
        dalsi_clanky = Clanek.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')[1:]
        paginator = Paginator(dalsi_clanky, 20) # ukáže dvacet dalších článků
        page_number = request.GET.get("page")
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

        context = {
            'bannery_1': bannery_1,
            'uvodni_clanek': uvodni_clanek,
            'page_obj': page_obj,
            'znac': znac,
            'rubr': rubr
            }
    return render(request, "zentour/clanky.html", context)
```

**html, single post:**

```
    <div class="odkazy_pod_clanky">
      <small>
        Značka:
          {% for z in clanek.znacka.all %}
            <a href="{% url 'clanky_vyber' zn=z.slug ru='' %}">{{ z }}, </a>
          {% endfor %}

        Rubrika: <a href="{% url 'clanky_vyber' zn='' ru=clanek.rubrika.slug %}">{{ clanek.rubrika }}</a>

              <!-- Zařazení: {{ clanek.urceni.all|join:", "}} -->
      </small> <br>
    </div>
```

**html, dropdowns (javascript) at page with list of posts:**

```
        <div class="rozbalovaci_znacka">
          <button onclick="rozbal_znacka()" class="menu_znacka">značka: {{ zna }}</button>
          <div id="rozbalovacka_znacka" class="polozky_k_rozbaleni_znacka">
            <a href="{% url 'clanky_vyber' zn="" %}">jakákoliv</a>
            {% for za in znac %}
              <a href="{% url 'clanky_vyber' zn=za.slug %}">{{ za.nazev_znacky }}</a>
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </div>

      <!-- třídění dle rubriky-->
      <div class="rozbalovaci_rubrika">
        <button onclick="rozbal_rubrika()" class="menu_rubrika">rubrika: {{ rub }}</button>
        <div id="rozbalovacka_rubrika" class="polozky_k_rozbaleni_rubrika">
          <a href="{% url 'clanky_vyber' ru="" %}">jakákoliv</a>
          {% for rb in rubr %}
            <a href="{% url 'clanky_vyber' ru=rb.rubrika.slug %}">{{ rb.rubrika }}</a>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
```

I have also tried to filter posts by *django-filters* and it worked, but I would prefer the solution above.
I am stacked in this for long time and I was not able to find a proper solution in existing questions on this site. Thank you, Pavel

Comment: `path("clanky/<slug:zn>/"` and `path("clanky/<slug:ru>/"` have *identical* patterns, so the second path will never "fire".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paths *overlap completely*. Indeed:

```
path("clanky/<slug:zn>/", views.clanek_vyber, name="clanky_vyber", kwargs={'ru': ''}),
path("clanky/<slug:ru>/", views.clanek_vyber, name="clanky_vyber", kwargs={'zn': ''}),
```

if the path is `clanky/foo` then both paths *match*. So it will check the paths in the order defined and thus always pick the *first* one, so with `zn` as value, and `ru` empty.

You thus should ensure that the paths do not overlap. Probably it is better that these do not overlap completely:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'clanky/zn/<slug:zn>/',
        views.clanek_vyber,
        name='clanky_vyber',
        kwargs={'ru': ''},
    ),
    path(
        'clanky/ru/<slug:ru>/',
        views.clanek_vyber,
        name='clanky_vyber',
        kwargs={'zn': ''},
    ),
    path(
        'clanky/znru/<slug:zn>/<slug:ru>/',
        views.clanek_vyber,
        name='clanky_vyber',
    ),
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, dear willeM_ Van Onsem, you helped me! Now it filters perfectly by "zn" or "ru".  Is there a way how to filter posts by both of these parameters?

Comment: @Pivel: with `'clanky/znru/<slug:zn>/<slug:ru>/',`? As long as the paths do not overlap, it should normally work. I'm writing on a small package to automatically check overlap :).

Comment: Yes! It works perfectly, I just have add the second parameter to those href links in html: <a href="{% url 'clanky_vyber' zn=za.slug ru=ru %}">{{ za.nazev_znacky }}</a> and here: <a href="{% url 'clanky_vyber' ru=rb.rubrika.slug zn=zn %}">{{ rb.rubrika }}</a> You wouldn’t believe, how much time I have spend solving this problem. And you solved it in couple minutes. I really appreciate your help!